# Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?

Tags: macros, comments

I have  experience where empty spaces cause unwanted effects. It is not easy to trace the cause of these unwanted effects. In order to eliminate any doubt, I often overuse % as follows.

```
\usepackage%
[%
left=3cm,
right=3cm%
]%
{geometry}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}%
{%
This is my command.%
}
```

I got an extreme example that will break what Leo Liu said

> In fact, only spaces which would be
>   output have to be removed by comment.

The following code does not produce output, but we cannot remove the `%` and leave a blank line between two elements of a list below.

```
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
gridwidth=0.4pt,
%
griddots=0
}
```

Shortly speaking, where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?

Comment: I think I've answered this somewhere else here already. Basically, spaces are always ignored after control words (i.e., control sequences consisting of `\` followed by letters). In the preamble (or in vertical mode more generally), spaces aren't important except in things like the replacement text of a macro.

Comment: @TH. : This previous question? [What is the use of percent signs at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

Comment: a blank line is not a space, but is converted into `\par`.

Comment: @Leo: Yeah, that's the one.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/multicolumn-listing-for-comparison-in-latex/22992#22992) overused `%`!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In fact, only spaces which would be output have to be removed by comment. And remember, spaces after a all-letter control sequence (also known as a control word as opposed to a control symbol) are ignored.

You can use:

```
\usepackage
[
  left  = 3cm,
  right = 3cm
]
{geometry}
```

It's Okey, no spaces will be output.

But you have to use:

```
\newcommand\foo
{% the space in \foo will be output when you use it in the text
  foo.%
}
```

That's why in TeX, package writers often use:

```
\newcommand\foo{%
  foo.}
```

---

In LaTeX3 macro syntax, all spaces (even between words) are ignored to ease macro writers. For example,

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \hello { m }
{
  hello~#1.
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The tilde `~` here is a normal space char.

---

In some packages, like `CJK`, writers use

```
\endlinechar \m@ne
```

to ignore the extra spaces introduced by newlines. Then you can use:

```
\newcommand\foo{
  foo.
}
```

and after all macros,

```
\endlinechar `\^^M
```

Comment: +1. It is a good answer but I will wait for a couple of days to get other answers with which your answer will be compared.

Answer (score 38):

I'd add some remarks to the nice answer by Leo Liu. Let's take a line from a package (it's not important to know which one)

```
\newcommand{\period@active}[1]{\begingroup\mathcode`\.="8000\ensuremath{#1}\endgroup}
```

This shows a common mistake that in the present example is actually innocuous, but only by chance, because `\ensuremath` expands to `\protect\ensuremath`  and usually `\protect` is unexpandable (or its expansion gives something that doesn't start with a number).

The command `\mathcode` requires two numbers (with an optional equals between them); it's the second one that's more important: since `"8000` is followed by a control sequence, TeX wants to expand it in order to see if its expansion starts with a (hexadecimal) digit. Were `\ensuremath` not robustified, its expansion would be

```
\ifmmode ... \else ... \fi
```

and the conditional would be evaluated at a possibly wrong time.

The moral of this is: *always leave a space after a constant* (i.e. an explicit number required by TeX's syntax). This space will be ignored and the following control sequence will not be expanded before the assignment.

A proper way to write that definition would be

```
\newcommand{\period@active}[1]{\begingroup\mathcode`\.="8000
  \ensuremath{#1}\endgroup}
```

(the end of line counts as a space, in this case).

There are cases when the constant *mustn't* be followed by a space, for example when we want to exploit `\romannumeral` or `\number` capabilities to expand everything that follows until finding something that can't be interpreted as a digit. However these are advanced LaTeX programming techniques (Ulrich Diez is a master in this field).

In the example case a `\relax` after the number would have done and it's commonly used for terminating assignments. It's definitely required after an *incomplete glue assignment*

```
\myskip=1pt plus 3pt\relax
```

which is the real equivalent to LaTeX's `\setlength{\myskip}{1pt plus 3pt}`.

However there are cases where `\relax` must be avoided: when comparing numbers or lengths, we frequently are in a *complete expansion* context and `\relax` would remain, since it's unexpandable: suppose we have a macro that must call different macros depending on the current value of a parameter `\X`

```
\def\xyz{\csname do\ifnum\X=10\relax a\else b\fi\endcsname}
```

would throw an error when `\X` holds the value 10. Of course this might be solved in many different ways, but

```
\def\xyz{\csname do\ifnum\X=10 a\else b\fi\endcsname}
```

is correct anyway.

Returning to the main question, there are some cases that sometimes fail to be considered. TeX always ignores spaces when looking for undelimited arguments. All macros defined with `\newcommand` use undelimited arguments, so

```
\parbox {3cm} {text}
\parbox
  {3cm}
  {text}
```

are perfectly equivalent. Also

```
\newcommand{\foo}
  {something}
```

is free of problems. For example, I usually suggest to set environment definitions like

```
\newenvironment{foo}[1]
  {begin}
  {end}
```

Of course if `begin` or `end` must be split into more than one line, the same rules about protecting from end-of-line characters hold.

One potential source of head scratching doesn't come from spurious spaces in the definition, but from TeX reading rules. Whenever the `begin` text in an environment typesets something or, more generally, starts a paragraph, the `begin` text must be terminated by `\ignorespaces`. Example: suppose that we want to add in front of a quotation a "title"; we can pass it to the new environment `xquotation` as

```
\newenvironment{xquotation}[1]
  {\begin{quotation}\noindent\textbf{#1} --- \ignorespaces}
  {\end{quotation}
```

Without `\ignorespaces` the input

```
\begin{xquotation}{Murphy}
If something can fail, it will.
\end{xquotation}
```

would have *two* spaces between the dash and "If". This space is exactly the end-of-line after the argument, which is not considered if `\ignorespaces` is in force. This problem does not appear if the environment *ends* a paragraph in its `begin` part and does not start one, since spaces are ignored in vertical mode.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `\relax` after a number, especially a glue. For example, `1pt plus 1pt\relax`, then a `minus` after it will be safe.

Answer (score 5):

What Leo Liu said is general true. In general a line break is equivalent to a white space. But a blank line is not. A blank line is usually interpreted as the same as `\par`.

And without `\long` a `\def` containing a `\par` will break. And this why a blank line will break many code if no `%` is appended. It is not about white space but about `\par`.

I suggest you read the chapter 20 of The TeXbook for a general knowledge of macro definitions. If it is not available, the book TeX by Topic, which is distributed with TeXLive, also has a good introduction to how TeX read in your input.

In summary, TeX is much a free-form language just like C/C++. The only main difference is that TeX interpret the special characters (new line, etc) based on the context (sometimes they are white space, sometimes they are `\par`, and sometimes they can be anything by assigning catcode). Knowing all these will help you to see clearly when you should use a `%` to comment out the newline.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).