# Do assignments need to be appended by % to remove the trailing white spaces?

Tags: counters, comments, dimensions

The following shows code snippet taken from `multido.tex`. I noticed assignments are not ended with `%`.

- See `\dimen@=#1\advance\dimen@#2` in

  ```
  \def\multido@step@d#1#2{%
    \dimen@=#1\advance\dimen@#2
    \edef#1{\number\dimen@ sp}}%
  ```
- See again `\count@=#1\advance\count@ by #2` in

  ```
  \def\multido@step@i#1#2{%
    \count@=#1\advance\count@ by #2
    \edef#1{\the\count@}}
  ```
- See again `\dimen@=#1pt`, `\dimen@=#2pt` and `\dimen@=#1pt\advance\dimen@#2` in

  ```
  \def\multido@init@r#1#2#3{%
    \dimen@=#1pt
    \multido@dimtonum\dimen@#3%
    \dimen@=#2pt
    \ifnum\multido@count<\z@\dimen@=-\dimen@\fi
    \multido@addtostep{\do\multido@step@r{\do#3}{\number\dimen@ sp}}}
  \def\multido@step@r#1#2{%
    \dimen@=#1pt\advance\dimen@#2
    \multido@dimtonum\dimen@#1}
  ```

Do assignments produce trailing white spaces that have to be ended with `%`?

Comment: Related: [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Example 1

```
\def\multido@step@d#1#2{%
  \dimen@=#1\advance\dimen@#2
  \edef#1{\number\dimen@ sp}}%
```

After `#2` there should be `\relax`. Indeed, if `#2` is a register or a parameter such as `\z@` or `\lineskip`, the space provided by the end of line would *not* be ignored. In this case also `%` might be used, because the following token is unexpandable (`\edef`). The token list got from `\multido@step@d{\x}{2pt}` would be (I denote the space token with •)

```
\dimen@=\x\advance\dimen@2pt•\edef\x{\number\dimen@ sp}
```

and the space before `\edef` would be ignored. But with `\multido@step@d{\x}{\parindent} one would have

```
\dimen@=\x\advance\dimen@\parindent•\edef\x{\number\dimen@ sp}
```

and the space token would *not* be ignored. The fact that it follows a control word is irrelevant: the tokenization phase has already taken place. With `\relax` after `#2` there would be `\relax` in place of the space token.

### Example 2

It's just the same. There should be `\relax` after `#2`

### Example 3

I'll number lines for clarity.

```
1    \def\multido@init@r#1#2#3{%
2      \dimen@=#1pt
3      \multido@dimtonum\dimen@#3%
4      \dimen@=#2pt
5      \ifnum\multido@count<\z@\dimen@=-\dimen@\fi
6      \multido@addtostep{\do\multido@step@r{\do#3}{\number\dimen@ sp}}}
7    \def\multido@step@r#1#2{%
8      \dimen@=#1pt\advance\dimen@#2
9      \multido@dimtonum\dimen@#1}
```

There's no need of terminating lines 2 and 4 with `%`; actually a `%` at the end of line 4 would be wrong, because TeX would start expanding `\ifnum` before having performed the assignment to `\dimen@` (probably harmless, in this particular case).

The same problem as before is at line 3: the `%` is good here, because the following token is `\dimen@` that's unexpandable; `\relax` would have been better.

Line 8 should have `\relax` at the end, for the same reasons as before; not a `%`, because an argument `#2` such as `2pt` would trigger the expansion of `\multido@dimtonum` before the assignment has been performed.

Answer (score 7):

When TeX is scanning for the dimension, unless the quantity being stored is presented in the form of a register, it will continue looking for the number and unit (expanding along the way) until reaching a space or inappropriate character.  The space is removed; thus, assignments written as you show them functionally have the same behavior as control words in removing the following whitespace.  And of course, if the dimension *is* a register then the register name will either be a control word itself (thus swallowing the space) or will be a number that TeX will scan for...

That said, *some* of the assignments you show use an argument (like `#2`) for the dimension.  Someone sneaky or too clever could use a register for that, and then the space would not be eaten because it would be written into the macro definition before the control word is read.  In practice, when such data is not under the control of the programmer, it is better to just kill the space with a `\relax`.

Comment: I think you need to use more specific name, i.e., **control word** instead of **control sequence** for the sake of clearness. What about the counter?

Comment: `\empty` would just eat the end-of-line at definition time, but wouldn't solve the next token expansion issue when the argument is an explicit `<dimen>`.