# Chapter number alignment with \titleformat

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

Sorry if this problem already emerged in here!

I'd like to see how to "push" the red number of the chapter to be aligned with the paragraphs. As you can see bellow, the red number is a slightly far from right margin than paragraph.

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,twoside=true,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,includemp,top=2.25cm,left=3.75cm,right=0.75cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{charter}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\usekomafont{chapter}}
    {\vspace{-5.5em}\raggedleft{
        {\color{green}
            \rule[0pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad
        {\color{red}
            \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}
        }
   }
   {-1.1em}
   {\raggedright}
   %[\vspace{-.55ex}\titlerule]

\setcounter{chapter}{13}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pairing Lattices}
The cryptographic importance of efficiently computable, bilinear and non-degenerate pairings that are hard to invert in various ways has been amply demonstrated. The currently only known instantiations of pairings suitable for cryptography are the Weil and Tate pairings on elliptic curves or on Jacobians of more general algebraic curves. In view of the applications, efficient algorithms for computing these pairings are of great importance.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two missing end-of-line comment signs produced spurious spacing. See [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces)

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,twoside=true,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,includemp,top=2.25cm,left=3.75cm,right=0.75cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{charter}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{25}{25}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\usekomafont{chapter}}
    {\vspace{-5.5em}\raggedleft{
        {\color{green}
            \rule[0pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad
        {\color{red}
            \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}% <-- Crucial comment sign
        }% <-- Crucial comment sign
   }
   {-1.1em}
   {\raggedright}
   %[\vspace{-.55ex}\titlerule]

\setcounter{chapter}{13}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Pairing Lattices}
The cryptographic importance of efficiently computable, bilinear and non-degenerate pairings that are hard to invert in various ways has been amply demonstrated. The currently only known instantiations of pairings suitable for cryptography are the Weil and Tate pairings on elliptic curves or on Jacobians of more general algebraic curves. In view of the applications, efficient algorithms for computing these pairings are of great importance.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so it was all about spacing?

Comment: @Thomas Indeed. Missing comment signs are the "usual suspects" for spurious space.