# Evenly spaced subfigures with twocolumn

Tags: two-column

In the `article` class with `twocolumn` option, I can set figures which spread all over the column space with `figure` and all over the text space with `figure*`. I have two subfigures, containing a picture, in a text-space figure and I want the inner pictures to be horizontally aligned with the corresponding ones in column-space figures (all pictures have the same width):

[image: lengths and goal]

Using [image: w_t] for `textwidth`, [image: w_c] for `columnwidth`, [image: w] for the picture width, [image: h_f] for the space occupied by `hfill` and [image: h_s] for a `hspace` set to an arbitrary value.

To achieve this, I can use an adjustable `hspace` just as following:

```
\null\hfill
{picture 1}
\hspace{\hs} % adjustable space
{picture 2}
\hfill\null
```

And I can determine the adjustable space `hs` for the pictures to be horizontally aligned:

[image: hs]

But I get an unwanted space on the right:

[image]

What is wrong?

MWE:
(I have used the `lipsum` package to adjust figures so as to be close each other.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\pict}
\setlength{\pict}{5cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
%
\begin{figure*}
  \null\hfill
  %
  \rule{\pict}{1cm}
  %
  \newlength{\hs}% adjustable space
  \setlength{\hs}{\linewidth-\columnwidth-\pict}%
  \hspace{\hs}%
  %
  \rule{\pict}{1cm}
  %
  \hfill\null
\end{figure*}
%
\lipsum[4-5]
\lipsum[11]
%
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \rule{\pict}{1cm}
\end{figure}
%
\lipsum[7-11]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in various other topics, the problem comes from line breaks ([What's causing extra white space to the left of my standalone TikZ image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137251/100137) by instance). So I have to add comments at the end of pictures lines:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \null\hfill
  %
  \rule{\pict}{1cm}% here
  %
  \newlength{\hs}% adjustable space
  \setlength{\hs}{\linewidth-\columnwidth-\pict}%
  \hspace{\hs}%
  %
  \rule{\pict}{1cm}% and here
  %
  \hfill\null
\end{figure*}
```