# Mis-alignment of columns in tabular environment when using ulem (and beamer)

Tags: beamer, text-decorations, ulem

I have not been able to find a solution to the following problem in the `ulem` documentation.  Could somebody help, please?

When I use a `ulem` macro to strike through some text in the tabular environment I would like the text to be aligned still.  I think the following MWE demonstrates the problem.

Many thanks,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand\tst{ % thick strike through
  \bgroup
  \markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[.8ex]{1pt}{0.8pt}}}
  \ULon
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  \frametitle{Meeting Times}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
Lecture Hours: & &\tst{{Tue. 17h00}} & \tst{\emph{S117}}\\
               & & Tue. 14h00  & \emph{KB118}\\
               & & Thu. 16h00  & \emph{S117}\\[.5ex]
Tutorials      & \textbf{3B} & Tue. 10h00 & \emph{SR2027} \\
               & \tst{\textbf{3A}} & \tst{Tue. 14h00} & \tst{\emph{KB118}}\\[.5ex]
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have written command `\tst` introduces an `unwanted space` which breaks column alignment. If you look at `ulem` manual, will see

```
\newcommand\cmd{\bgroup \markoverwith{hsomethingi}\ULon}
```

without any separation before `\ULon` command. So just change your code to

```
\newcommand\tst{ % thick strike through
  \bgroup
  \markoverwith{\textcolor{red}{\rule[.8ex]{1pt}{0.8pt}}}% <- add %
  \ULon
}
```

and your tabular will look well aligned.

[image]

If you want to read something else about unwanted spaces, look at (for example):

- [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces)
- [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)
- [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions)

Comment: Great.  That worked perfectly.  Many thanks.