# How to actually close a write-stream

Tags: tex-core, write-file

I don't know too much about writing and reading to and from files. But I managed to create a nice command for me where I need to write something into a text-file and later-on read it again.

```
\newcommand{\customwrite}[1]{
  \newwrite\tempfile%
  \immediate\openout\tempfile=filename_#1.txt%
  \immediate\write\tempfile{\the\figheight}%
  \immediate\closeout\tempfile%
}
```

The reading is achieved by

```
\newcommand{\customread}[1]{
  \newread\tempfile%
  \openin\tempfile=filename_#1.txt%
  \read\tempfile to \fileline%
  \setlength\figheightex\fileline%
  \closein\tempfile%
}
```

Both things works fine for me as long as I have not too much of this calls.
Recently, I had a bigger document and everything failed and I got the message `No room for a new \write`. I searched for this error and what I found is, Latex is only capable of opening 16 write and 16 read streams. Apparently `\closeout` and `\closein` don't actually close these streams what I thought.

My question is now: is it somehow possible to actually close these streams?

Comment: you can use `\tempfile` repeatedly, without more than one `\newwrite`. Or am I missing something? And you shloud have a seperate one `\mytempout` for writing and `\mytempin` for reading...

Comment: Ok, sorry. I truncated too much from my file. filename.txt actually changes by an optional argument, I corrected this in my posting. Furthermore, I can use `\tempfile` repeatedly. I only need this "variable" once while executing the command.

and since I always only execute one of the commands, it was working for me using the same "variable" `\tempfile` for writing and reading

Comment: @tohecz you should make that an answer.

Comment: @bene as tohez says just move the `\new....` out of the definitions and just execute them once in the preamble.

Comment: If you are just saving the height of a figure, why use a file at all rather than just save the macro?

Comment: ahh, now I got the comment from tohecz. I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks a lot tohecz, it works. The reason, why I save the height of a figure is, because I externalize pgfplots which I generated with matlab2tikz and set their height and width within my main latex document. And of course, I want to remake the figure if I changed the dimensions and that's how I do it at the moment. I don't know if there are better possibilities to realize that, but for me this flow now works perfectly.

Comment: @bene Usually there are better possibilities, but if this one works for you, it's fine :) and as well, this way you practice and improve your TeXnicianity! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You reserve a new read/write slot every time you read or write, but you don't need it. Moving `\new...` out of the definitions does the trick:

```
\newwrite\mytempout
\newcommand{\customwrite}[1]{%
  \immediate\openout\mytempout=filename_#1.txt %
  \immediate\write\mytempout{\the\figheight}%
  \immediate\closeout\mytempout
}

\newread\mytempin
\newcommand{\customread}[1]{%
  \openin\mytempin=filename_#1.txt %
  \read\mytempin to \fileline
  \setlength\figheightex\fileline
  \closein\mytempin
}
```

I added and removed some of the `%`s to make it more reasonable, see e.g. [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces?lq=1)