# Piping shell command output to another command

Tags: input, debugging, shell-escape

I'm trying to write a command that wraps `\href` with a QR code to the given URL. For this I need to generate a temp file and reuse it later, so I wrote a `\mktemp` command that wraps the `mktemp` utility:

```
% Created 2023-06-03 Sat 13:05
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\newcommand{\mktemp}[0]{
  \input|"mktemp"
  %% /tmp/tempfile.png
}

\newcommand{\hrefqr}[3][\mktemp]{
  \immediate\write18{qrencode #2 -o #1}
  \href{#2}{#3 \includegraphics[]{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\hrefqr{www.example.com}{This is example.com}
\end{document}
```

If I hard-code the \mktep filename, the document above compiles, but when I replace the hard-coded filename with `\input|"mktemp"`, I get a weird error:

```
 This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/ealfonso/git/keto/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./test.out) (./test.out)
! Use of \\hrefqr doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.20 \hrefqr{www.example.com}{This is example.com}
                                                  
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I tried looking into the `test.log` but couldn't find any meaningful debug info.

1. What is the proper way to pipe the output of a command like `mktemp` into another command?
2. What is a good general way to debug obscure-looking latex compile errors?
3. I've seen [references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137111/how-to-actually-close-a-write-stream) to a `\tempfile` command, but I just get: `! Undefined control sequence. \mktemp -> \tempfile` when trying to use it. Where is this `\tempfile` command defined?

I should note that I have modified my `textmf.cnf` to allow the commands `qrencode` and `mktemp`:

```
shell_escape_commands = \
bibtex,bibtex8,\
extractbb,\
gregorio,\
kpsewhich,\
makeindex,\
repstopdf,\
r-mpost,\
texosquery-jre8,\
qrencode,\
touch,\
mktemp,\
tr,\
mktemp-no-newline.sh,\
```

Comment: `catchfile` package

Comment: Just a note: QR codes can be generated without shell escape, e.g., using [package `qrcode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode). There are [several other possibilities](https://ctan.org/topic/qrcode).

Comment: @cabohah thanks, the `qrcode` package is what I needed, please feel free to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [XY problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2449/277964) and you should have asked for making QR codes with LaTeX. There are [several packages for this](https://ctan.org/topic/qrcode). Here a short example using [package `qrcode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\qrcode*{This is example.com without link}

\href{www.example.com}{\qrcode*{This is example.com}}

\qrcode{www.example.com}

\end{document}
```

[image: three qr codes, first without, second and third with link]

Comment: There are 3 questions, one is about how to embed a qr code. The other two are about how to use and debug latex macros. Your answer is helpful and answers one of the questions. Perhaps I should have asked 3 separate questions instead.

Comment: @user84207 Yes, you should *always* ask only one question. And I've even not answered *any* of your questions, but the underlying problem. You should also always tell your real problem, not only the problem with your try to solve it. See the first link in my answer.

Comment: Even if I know how to use the `qrcode` package, which is very helpful, in general I would also like to know how to implement such a utility myself and to debug latex programs.

Comment: @user84207 Just ask more questions — if they have not already have been asked like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex or if the current questions and answers are not sufficient. In last case, you should explain your difference resp. additional needs.