# Inconsistent column placement in beamer slides with overlay

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays, columns

I'm trying to show alternative column configurations on a beamer slide, as shown in this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1cm);}
        \end{column}
        \only<1>{\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1cm);}
        \end{column}}
        \only<2>{\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1cm);}
        \end{column}}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here, I create two identical columns right of a column that stays the same during all slides. However, it is positioned differently on slide 1 and 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code introduces an unwanted space at the end of second column which moves them between first and second slide. If you add `%` at the end of `\end{colum}}` lines, your problem will be solved.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1cm);}
        \end{column}
        \only<1>{\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1cm);}
        \end{column}}% <--- comment here
        \only<2>{\begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
            \tikz{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, 1cm);}
        \end{column}}% <--- comment here
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Some more information about about unwanted spaces:

- [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces)
- [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)
- [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions)