# Reducing margin as small as possible in subfigure

Tags: margins, subfloats

I use subfigure to implement subfigure and I use `\hspace` or `\vspace`. I want very small margin to maximize the size of subfigures but when I set `\hspace{0cm}` and `\vspace{0cm}`, there is still large enough margin left between 2 subfigures hence I can not maximize subfigure size. How to solve this problem? My code is like this :

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering

\subfigure[11a's TX rate]{
\includegraphics[scale =0.25] {fig/cdf_rate11a.eps}
\label{cdf_rate11a}
}
\hspace{0cm}
\subfigure[11n's TX rate]{
\includegraphics[scale =0.25] {fig/cdf_rate11n.eps}
\label{cdf_rate11n}
}

\caption{Coverage comparison in various location}
\label{coverage_comparison}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: `hspace` _adds_ space and `\hspace{0pt}` adds no space, compare `hello\hspace{0pt}world` with `hello\hspace{3cm}world` (At the start of a paragraph, as you had used it it does nothing at all)

Comment: Have you tried a negative space? like ``\hspace{-1cm}``

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! First, note that the `subfigure` package is considered deprecated, use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead. Second, a line break inserts a space, so you need to for example add `%` at the end of some lines (see e.g. [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)).

Comment: @Timmy sorry I was wrong (it was not at the start of the paragraph, I'd misread the example) I deleted the comment.

Comment: Thank you, I add some % in the end of some lines and margin is reduced well now. And I can also use negative space in this case I use \hspace{-0.5cm}. Now there is no useless margin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you're looking to place two subfigures side by side. In order to maximize their size, while also maximizing the available distance between them, don't specify a `scale` option in the `\includegraphics` instructions. Instead, specify a large value for the width of each `subfigure` environment -- e.g., `0.48\textwidth` -- and use the `width=\linewidth` option when executing `\includegraphics`. And, be sure to use an instruction such as `\hspace{\fill}` to maximize the separation between the subfigures.

The following image shows the resulting look. The thin horizontal line on top is drawn just to illustrate the width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subcaption}      % for 'subfigure'  environment
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' in your real document
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate the width of the text block
\begin{figure}[h!]
%%\centering  % not needed as the subfigures are maximally separated

\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig/cdf_rate11a.eps}
\caption{11a's TX rate}
\label{fig:cdf_rate11a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig/cdf_rate11n.eps}
\caption{11n's TX rate}
\label{fig:cdf_rate11n}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Coverage comparison in various locations}
\label{fig:coverage_comparison}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have an error while running that, I just use from \begin{figure} till \end{figure} : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.174 \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
                                       
?

Comment: @user2290560 - Are you maybe also loading either the `subfigure` or the `subfig` package, in addition to the `subcaption` package that's used in the example code above?

Comment: That error is disappeared when I comment subfigure package but another error happens : ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.81  }

Comment: @user2290560 - I'm afraid this new information isn't sufficient to diagnose what's going on. What's on line 81 (the line that contains the `\let` statement), and what are the instructions on the couple of lines that immediately precede the line that contain the `\let` statement? Do consider posting a new query, with a new MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that generates the error.

Comment: Indeed, it works when I just run your code. maybe the problem is with my additional codes. I will find it again

Answer (score 2):

The subfigures are positioned like a letter `X`.

If you go

XX

there is no space between them.

If you go

```
X
X
```

There is one word space between them.

Your usage is like

```
X
{}
X
```

with two word spaces between them

and

```
X

X
```

would put them one above the other in separate paragraphs