# When should one place an % at the end of a line to prevent the insertion of unwanted space

Tags: macros

I understand that a % character at the end of a line prevents the insertion of a space in the text. However when creating macros I am unclear when you should place a percent sign at
the end of a line, i.e. which are the `safe' macros that do not require a percent sign when they appear at the end of a line?

Is it better to always put a percent sign in macro code, unless you explicitly want a space?

E.g. \small & \selectfont do not seem to insert any unwanted space, but commands like \hspace & \rule do insert unwanted space (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922/5764)

Comment: Related: [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)