# Line breaks in code affecting outcome appearance (boxes)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, coding

I fear the answer to my question might be obvious to many of you, still I couldn't explain it to me.

Using a parbox in an fbox and changing the textcolor works out as desired.
But I came across a weird behaviour.

Depending on how I arrange the code the appearance changes:
For reasons of coding readability I like to put brackets into new lines sometimes. But this results in this very case to the fact that text is not centered any more but shifted a bit to the left.

Is this always the case? Is there a sensible reason for this behaviour?
Should I just stop coding that way?

Thanks in advance for your ideas and hints!
(fyi: I guess a mwe is not need so I just provide a screenshot of the code.

[image])

Comment: tex is designed for _text_ a newline is treated as a space

Comment: please don't post images of code, post reproducible documents on a code section `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: there are lots of questions that discuss extraneous spaces.  here are a few: [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453), [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946), [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

Comment: @barbarabeeton true although all those are asking about the answer (`%`) so not obvious to someone just knowing the question, so I didn't close as dup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- not asking for closure either.  just pointing to more ways to understand the problem once it's identified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect

```
one
two
three
```

to typeset as

> one two three

not

> onetwothree

then you should expect

```
\fbox{
abc
}
```

to typeset as

> | abc |

not

> |abc|

Either don't add the white space, or comment it out.

```
\fbox{abc}
```

or

```
\fbox{%
abc%
}
```

Comment: Ha David! Now I finally get why these %-signs at the end of lines are added. Thank You very much! This really really gave me some enlightment! :D