# Why wouldn't this tikz wrapper command place the text at the same spot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, remember

I'm trying to write a wrapper for command placement in a `beamer` document. I'm using `tikz` for this, and I created a new command:

```
\newcommand{\figz}[3]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor=west] at (#2,#3) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Which I call to, using:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Sun Hours Mismatch}

  \figz{text 1}{0}{0}
  \figz{text 2}{0}{0}
\end{frame}
```

The result is

[image]

While I expect something like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

Compileable example. The frame title represent to actual result, rather than the desired one.

```
\documentclass[xetex,mathserif,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\figz}[3]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor=west] at (#2,#3) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Overlap}

  \figz{text 1}{0}{0}
  \figz{text 2}{-0.39}{0}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{shifted}

  \figz{text 1}{0}{0}
  \figz{text 2}{0}{0}

\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a compilable example?

Comment: Sort of duplicate of [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) Add a `%` after `[3]{`, after `\end{tikzpicture}`, and also after the first use of `\figz` in the frame.

Comment: A complete example would be more helpful. Depending on that, the nodes may or may not have the same width.

Comment: @samcarter I uploaded a compileable example. Thank you.

Comment: @Yotam As Torbjørn T. mentioned in his comment, you are missing three `%` at the places he indicated.

Comment: @Yotam Off-topic: you should not use the obsolete options like `mathserif`. Please read the warning messages, they tell you how to replace them.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Seems you guessed right. Do you want to answer? Or close as a duplicate?

Comment: See also [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946) and [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)