# Extra spacing in \ref or \eqref

Tags: spacing, equations, cross-referencing

I changed the equation numbering format to avoid the 0 when I don't have subsubsection. Output ex. :

> *Equation* (1.1.a)

instead of

> *Equation* (1.1.0.a)

But now, when I use the `\ref` or the `\eqref` commands, they are extra spacing before the parenthesis. Output ex. :

> ( 1.1.a )

instead of

> (1.1.a)

Do you have any solution?

**Full Latex example :**

```
\documentclass [11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  .\alph{equation}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

   \subsection{Subsection}
      \begin{equation}
       equation = 1
      \label{eq1}
      \end{equation}

      \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
         \begin{equation}
          equation = 2
         \label{eq2}
         \end{equation}

   \subsection{Ref.}
       Eqref for First equation \eqref{eq1}
       Ref for Second equation (\ref{eq2})

\end{document}
```

Output :

> [image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unprotected end of lines! See

- [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946),
- [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453) and
- [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{% <--- HERE
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  .\alph{equation}% <--- HERE
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please observe percent signs in lines marked `here`:

```
\documentclass [11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{% here
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
  \thesubsection
  \else
  \thesubsubsection
  \fi
  .\alph{equation}% here
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

   \subsection{Subsection}
      \begin{equation}
       equation = 1
      \label{eq1}
      \end{equation}

      \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
         \begin{equation}
          equation = 2
         \label{eq2}
         \end{equation}

   \subsection{Ref.}
       Eqref for First equation \eqref{eq1}
       Ref for Second equation (\ref{eq2})

\end{document}
```

[image]