# Raised progressbar in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am making a beamer presentation using [this](http://jmckalex.org/files/beamerouterthemeprogressbarjma.sty) outertheme based on the more famous [progressbar](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php) outertheme.

It all works fine when I compile the first time:

[image]

However, when I compile the second time in order for the progressbar to show the actual progress based on the number of slides, the progressbar is raised from the bottom of the page:

[image]

Here's the MWE that generates the slide above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\useoutertheme{progressbarjma}

\begin{document}

\frame{Test slide 1}
\frame{Test slide 2}

\end{document}
```

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: They don't, except in one case where the answer is in the comments and I cannot accept it.

Comment: In that case, you can ask that user to post a proper answer. In the other cases, you do of course have the option of posting a comment explaining what is wrong with/missing from a given answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In line 454 of `beamerouterthemeprogressbarjma.sty`, add a `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`. I.e. go from

```
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to

```
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

The `tikzpicture` itself is `\paperwidth` wide, the space made by the linebreak after `\end{tikzpicture}` seems to add a new line in the output, thus pushing the progressbar up. Adding the `%` gives this:

[image]

For more on end-of-line `%`, see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453), [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946) and [Where are the necessary places to be appended with % to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)