# Left-justified text appears not to properly be aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

If I have this:

```
\end{multicols}
\hrulefill
\begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{
        TOTAL FINANCIAL OUTLAY
        \newline
        \$66,179.62USD and \$9,634.31CAD
    }
\end{flushleft}
\pagebreak
```

It renders like so:

[image]

With the dollar sign to the left of the 'T' in 'Total'.  This looks and feels 'off' to me.  I can't figure out why it does that, and how to have it left-align both sentences properly.  Note they're both contained in the `\begin{flushleft}[...]\end{flushleft}`

I'm generating a PDF with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add a `%` after `\textbf{` to comment the implicit space added by the line end: `\textbf{%`

Comment: Ah, that did it. I had tried putting the text on the same line and hadn't noticed that it had resolved the issue, so I had changed it back.  Thank you.  If you submit your comment as an answer I will accept it right away.

Comment: This question explains the proper use of `%`:  [Where are the necessary places to be appended with `%` to remove unwanted spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under normal circumstances TeX understands a (single) line break as a space. That's why writing:

```latex
hello
world
```

produces "hello world" in the PDF output. The same rule goes with:

```latex
a\textbf{
  TOTAL
}b
```

which will output `a TOTAL b`.

The usual way to circumvent this space added by TeX is to comment out the line end. This code:

```latex
a\textbf{%
  TOTAL%
}b
```

produces `aTOTALb` (note that spaces at the beginning of the line, before `TOTAL`, are ignored).

However since you are making the entire contents of the environment bold, I'd suggest you use `\bfseries` instead of `\textbf`, so you don't have to worry about that. I'd also use a blank line instead of `\newline`:

```latex
\begin{flushleft}
  \bfseries
  TOTAL FINANCIAL OUTLAY

  \$66,179.62\,USD and \$9,634.31\,CAD
\end{flushleft}
```

(You don't need to add a `%` after `\bfseries` because TeX ignores spaces after command names.)